# Algunos estilos no se aplican en dispositivos Samsung

Tags: html, css, samsung

Tengo un formulario al que no se le están aplicando alguno de los estilos CSS, pero solo en dispositivos Samsung, por eso acudo a su ayuda. Les dejo el código:

PHP

```
<div class="contenedorValoraciones">
    <div class="estrellasComentario">
        <?php 
        for($i=0;$i<$fila_comentarios["puntuacion"];$i++){
        ?>
            <p class="puntuacion">&#9733; </p>
        <?php           
        }
        ?>
        <h3 class="usuario"><?php echo utf8_encode($fila_comentarios["usuario"]); ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="fecha"><?php echo $fila_comentarios["fecha"]; ?></div>
    <div class="mostrarComentario"><?php echo utf8_encode($fila_comentarios["comentario"]); ?></div>
</div>
```

CSS (los estilos señalados con los asteriscos son los que no se están aplicando correctamente)

```
.puntuacion{
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  color: orange;    /* No se aplica */
}

.estrellas{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ccc;      /* No se aplica */
}

.estrellas:hover{
  color: orange;    /* No se aplica */
}

.estrellas:hover ~ .estrellas{
  color: orange;    /* No se aplica */
}

.formularioComentarios input[type = "radio"]:checked ~ label{
  color: orange;    /* No se aplica */
}
```

Comment: Has probado si en lugar de poner el nombre del color, pones su equivalente en RGB o Hexadecimal? Por ejemplo: color: #FFB300;

Comment: hola desafortunadamente eso no funciono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe una [pregunta en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25566195/3695983) donde se indica que parece que esto es un problema con la fuente que usa Samsung en sus dispositivos y sólo con algunos símbolos (entre ellos la estrella cuyo código es `&#9733;`).

En esa pregunta se sugieren dos posibles soluciones:

1. Especificar una fuente específica para los iconos: [Eldok sugiere Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select), pero podría valer cualquier otra que tenga la estrella y te guste, importándola usando [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face). Algo como esto (nota que deberías quitar el contenido del `p` con clase `puntuacion`):

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'icomoon';
       src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?4n7iw5');
       src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix4n7iw5') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('fonts/icomoon.woff?4n7iw5') format('woff'),
           url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?4n7iw5') format('truetype'),
           url('fonts/icomoon.svg?4n7iw5#icomoon') format('svg');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
   }

   .puntuacion {
     font-family: 'icomoon';
     color: orange;
   }

   .puntuacion:before {
     content: "\e600";
   }
   ```
2. Usar la sombra de la letra en lugar de la letra en sí: [Craig sugiere usar `text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow), que no requeriría importar nada nuevo al proyecto, y que si lo pones sin ningún difuminado, se vería igual que la letra. Algo como esto:

   ```
   .puntuacion {
     color: transparent;  
     text-shadow: 0 0 0 orange;
   }
   ```

Comment: hola, si ya lo había solucionado con el truco de text-shadow. De todas formas gracias por tu respuesta.